# Function as response value in JS

Tags: javascript

I found the following example in a course and I don't understand it.

This code takes two arguments, in this case two years, and returns true if 1912 is within those two years, otherwise the result is false. Example:

```js
function yearToCheck(year) {
  return function(x, y) {
    return year >= x && year <= y;
  }
}

const checkYears = yearToCheck(1912);

checkYears(1900, 1913) // true 
checkYears(1900, 1911) // false
```

The code works. I just want ot undestand why does the anonymous function "function (x, y)" take the values 1900 and 1913/1911 from the variable checkYears?

Comment: Not much of a question here. You call a function (`yearToCheck`), the return value (assigned to `checkYears`) is a function that takes 2 parameters. Call it with parameters and get the result of the logical condition contained within that function (i.e. a boolean). The code here is very readable.

Comment: [Documentation on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).